# Apply multiple scopes to Laravel model without overrride [5.6]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I want to filter Store model with filters like targets, prices and products with the following conditions:

- All of them allow **multiple choice**, so I always gonna pass an array.
- Always I have to use the **AND operator**. If I try to filter by price = $ and target = men, the query should be something like 'WHERE price_range = $ AND target = men'.

When I am trying to do the filtering, the query always returns a wrong result. For example, I have a store with price_range = $ and target = men. When I filter by price_range = $ and target = women, that store appear on the result, and that's wrong.

This is my **Store model**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Store extends Model
{
    public function values()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Value');
    }

    public function targets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Target');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }

    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('is_active', true);
    }

    public function scopePrices($query, $priceRanges = [])
    {
        if ($priceRanges) {
            return $query->whereIn('price_range', $priceRanges);
        }
    }

    public function scopeValues($query, $values = [])
    {
        if ($values) {
            return $query->whereHas('values', function ($query) use ($values) {
                $query->whereIn('name', $values);
            });
        }
    }

    public function scopeTargets($query, $targets = [])
    {
        if ($targets) {
            return $query->whereHas('targets', function ($query) use ($targets) {
                $query->whereIn('name', $targets);
            });
        }


    }

    public function scopeProducts($query, $products = [])
    {
        if ($products) {
            return $query->whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($products) {
                $query->whereIn('name', $products);
            });
        }
    }

}
```

And this is my **getStores() from StoresController**:

```
 public function getStores()
    {
        $stores = Store::active()
            ->prices(request('price_ranges'))
            ->values(request('values'))
            ->targets(request('targets'))
            ->products(request('products'))
            ->orderBy('name')
            ->get();

        return response()->json($stores);
    }
```

I would like to do this with scopes because I think is a clean way to do it. Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have defined **$priceranges** as array `$priceRanges = []` in your scopes.

Just replace all arrays like `$priceRanges = []` with `$priceRanges` and it will work i guess. Because while you define scope, there is no need of defining `$priceRanges = []`.

example

```
public function scopePrices($query, $priceRanges)
{
    if ($priceRanges) {
        return $query->whereIn('price_range', $priceRanges);
    }
}
```

Just read this document [Laravel query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes).

Comment: @kerbholz yes that is almost same. Anyway, I am updating it. thanks for the suggestion.